# Upload local files to a virtual machine using putty

Tags: wordpress, ssh, upload, putty

my company asked me to transfer their wordpress websites (web and database files) to another server. The other server is a virtual machine which is already running and there is already an empty shell. I have the username, ip address and password of the virtual machine where they want to transfer the file. I was able to login to the virtual machine using putty and double check the directory of that virtual machine and it seems that there is nothing yet. And I've downloaded the wordpress files and its database in local computer. And the local computer that I'm going to use dont have any internet connect but I was able to connect to the virtual machine using putty.
Questions:
- how can I transfer the wordpress files from the local computer to the virtual machine using putty?
- what command line should I type to upload the wordpress files? The command line that I've tried is this below. I logged in on the virtual machine and type the command line below. And it seems that it didnt work.
scp root@127.0.0.1:C:\Users\localComputer\Desktop\wordpress.zip /home/virtualMachine
- should I login on the virtual machine via putty and then type in the command line to upload the files from the local computer OR use command prompt from the windows and type the command lines to upload the files to the virtual machine?

The local computer Im using is windows 7 32bit. Please advise. Also, I dont know how to unzip the files once it is uploaded in the virtual machine. what command line should I used.

Comment: How were you able to connect to putty through your local computer without any internet connection ? :)

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Okay. I do apologize for this. I will move this topic there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well you cant upload files from your local computer through putty, you have ftp for that. To upload files from your local computer you have a couple of options.

1. Upload to a git repository like github and bitbucket
2. Check if ftp is installed and then connect through ftp.

For ftp you might first have to check if ftp is installed and then create a new user which you can then use to ftp into the server. I personally like git so i will just explain about git.

If its your first time using git, then it might be a bit tricky. But none the less you will have to learn it for the long run. Create an account on github or bitbucket, if your code is copyrighted/ Ultra top secret :P and dont want anyone to get hands on it then you have to upload it to a private repository, while if its just a wordpress theme or nothing much of any value then you can upload it to a public repository and later delete it **(bitbucket has free private repositories while you have to pay for github)**.

After creating the account, create a new repository with the name of the project.

I personally like github, so i will explain for github. But 99% of the things are same for bitbucket as well.

First install the github **globally** on your OS, Once installed goto the directory you want to upload and type, these commands

```
git init
git add *
git commit -m "Upload code to server"
git remote add origin <github-repository-url>
git push -u origin master
```

if asked for username/pass just type it in. This will upload the code to github. Then on your server first install git by

```
sudo yum install git-all // For redhats e.g fedora, centos etc
                 OR 
sudo apt-get install git-all // for debian e.g ubuntu
```

Then goto the directory you want to upload your code to and type.

```
git init
git clone <github-repository-url> .
```

Dot is important, as it tells the server to download the code in the directory that you are currently inside. Then it will start downloading all the code to your server.

**Making changes like a pro**

Lets say later on you want to make changes to the files on your local computer. After you make all the changes, just type

```
git add *
git commit -m "My new changes"
git push
```

And it will upload all the changes to repository you defined in the previous steps.

Then on your server, you can just type

```
git pull
```

And it will pull all the changes from the respository.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I will try your steps and hope it will work.